# R Subsetting Specific Value Also Returns NA?

Tags: r, vector, subset

I am just starting out on learning R and came across a piece of code as follows

```
vec_1 <- c("a","b", NA, "c","d")

# create a subet of all elements which equal "a"
vec_1[vec_1 == "a"]
```

The result from this is

```
## [1] "a" NA
```

Im just curious, since I am subsetting `vec_1` for the value "a", why does `NA` also show up in my results?

Comment: Because NA is not equal to anything, even another NA. So any logical test with an NA in either side of an operator returns NA. That's just what R does. I think it's silly and annoying but I haven't been able to get much traction on htat opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the result of anything `== NA` is `NA`. Even `NA == NA` is `NA`.

Here's the output of `vec_1 == "a"` -

`[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE`

and `NA` is not `TRUE` or `FALSE` so when you subset anything by `NA` you get `NA`. Check this out -

```
vec_1[NA]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

When dealing with `NA`, `R` tries to provide the most informative answer i.e. `T | NA` returns `TRUE` because it doesn't matter what `NA` is. Here are some more examples -

```
T | NA
[1] TRUE

F | NA
[1] NA

T & NA
[1] NA

F & NA
[1] FALSE
```

R has no way to test equality with `NA`. In your case you can use `%in%` operator -

```
5 %in% NA
[1] FALSE

"a" %in% NA
[1] FALSE

vec_1[vec_1 %in% "a"]
[1] "a"
```